# What is this dllhost.exe process doing with my video files?

Tags: windows-10, process, multimedia

On my Windows 10 Home x64 machine, I noticed an unknown instance of `dllhost.exe` using a high amount of CPU. Upon further inspection, I noticed that it had one thread using most of its CPU time. Here's the thread stack:

[image: A thread stack highlighting mfmkvsrcsnk.dll]

Based on some more digging this specific DLL is a microsoft signed DLL called "Media Foundation MKV Media Source and Sink DLL". If I look at the process's file handles, it has an open file handle to a video file in my user directory, specifically a .webm video capture of one of my virtual machines.

[image]

Is this some sort of malware hiding behind legitimate Windows DLLs using some kind of COM interfaces? Or is this a legitimate Windows function? If so, what is it doing with my video files?

Comment: Wow!  Good debugging! COM+.. check.  MKV synch dll.. check.. I am just as bewildered as you.  It looks like to me that it is trying to exit and something happened in the kernel thread synchronization at the top of the stack.  Probably not malicious.. but who knows?  If you have the skills, you could always look to the SetLastWin32Error() call to see what the error was.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thanks! I no longer have the process running at the moment, but if I see it again I'll try to have a debugger ready so I can see more than just the stack instruction pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the COM Surrogate, maybe Windows Explorer tried to extract thumbnails or other properties for your videos ?

You can learn more about the COM Surrogate here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090212-00/?p=19173

basically:

> Explorer uses the COM Surrogate when extracting thumbnails, for
>   example. If you go to a folder with thumbnails enabled, Explorer will
>   fire off a COM Surrogate and use it to compute the thumbnails for the
>   documents in the folder. It does this because Explorer has learned not
>   to trust thumbnail extractors; they have a poor track record for
>   stability. Explorer has decided to absorb the performance penalty in
>   exchange for the improved reliability resulting in moving these dodgy
>   bits of code out of the main Explorer process. When the thumbnail
>   extractor crashes, the crash destroys the COM Surrogate process
>   instead of Explorer.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to make sense given the handles that the process held when I came across it.